# Zip file download in **laravel 5.4 ** from public directory using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.4

In my `laravel` app there is a zip file in my public path I want to download it using ajax not return zip file and throw an error which shown in image anybody help to solve this problem thanks in advance.

```
$files = glob(public_path('uploads/download-images'));
            \Zipper::make(public_path('uploads/product_images.zip'))->add($files)->close();
            return response()->download(public_path('uploads/product_images.zip'));
```

this is ajax

```
var join_selected_values = allVals.join(",");
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('url'),
                type: 'POST',
                data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
                data: 'ids='+join_selected_values,
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    window.location = data;
                    alert('Seccussfully Downloaded');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: This question is related to CodeIgniter or laravel ?

Comment: this is related to laravel

Comment: So, Don't use CI tag in question.

Comment: @ShahidHussain how did you go?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this might have something to do with you having to set `header configuration` for the response. You have to change the content-type to your desired one of course. I hope it helps.

```
{
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization , Access-Control-Request-Headers',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'
        ];
    return response()->download(filepathHere, nameHere, $headers);
}
```

Also make sure:

> Symfony HttpFoundation, which manages file downloads, requires the file being downloaded to have an ASCII file name.

Comment: not work bro and why pdf not zip 'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'

Comment: As I said in my answer: You have to change the content-type to your desired one of course.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you can't return a download response using Ajax calls. The work around is, don't use an ajax request to download. Just do a traditional request. Because it returns a download response, the browser will automatically open the download dialog, so it will be similar to a no refresh.